# Double Summation expression in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have a Parameter matrix, C of size 2x2. It looks like this.

```
C= [2 4; 6 8]
```

I have a decision variable, X of size 2x2. It looks like this

```
[ X('S1', 'D1')    X('S1', 'D2') ]
[ X('S2', 'D1')    X('S2', 'D2') ]
```

I want to formulate my Objective Function as a series of double expression (Please refer the attachment),

[image]

Which shall look like the following after the expansion.

```
Z = 2*X('S1', 'D1')  + 4*X('S1', 'D2') + 6*X('S2', 'D1')  + 8*X('S2', 'D2')
```

I try the following.

```
Z = sum(C.*X,1);
```

But it creates An optimizationExpression of size 1x3, which is not desired.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any easier way to do so without using for loop. I have just started learning "Problem-Based Optimization" in MATLAB today. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Z = sum(C(:).*X(:))` ?

Comment: @Sardar Usama, Can you please explain me the logic behind this?
I have triple summation and more expressions in the future problem.

Comment: btw you wrote you were getting an optimization expression of size 1x3. It should be 1x2.

Comment: Yes It was be 1x3. Sorry for the typing mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `C` and `X` are 2x2 matrices, so `C.*X` gives a 2x2 matrix. With `sum(C.*X,1);`, summation is done along the first dimension (i.e. rows are added). But you want to sum all the elements. So if you convert your matrices into a vector and then multiply element-wise and then apply `sum`, it will add all the elements i.e.

```
Z = sum(C(:).*X(:));
```

Alternatively, you can first multiply and then convert the result into a vector before applying `sum`.

```
CX = C.*X;
Z = sum(CX(:));
```

or sum along all the dimensions one by one. But I'd go with the solution suggested in the beginning.